# HTML form name array parsing in Pyramid (Python)

Tags: python, html, forms, pyramid

Is there any way for [Pyramid](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/1.0/) to process HTML form input which looks like this:

```
<input type="text" name="someinput[]" value="" />
```

or even more usefully:

```
<input type="text" name="someinput[0][subelement1]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="someinput[0][subelement2]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="someinput[1][subelement1]" value="" />
<input type="text" name="someinput[1][subelement2]" value="" />
```

...and access that data easily (e.g. via a dict)?

Any help would be much appreciated!

**EDIT:** to make it clearer, what I need is the ability to have a form where a user can add as many 'instances' of a group of input elements, e.g. adding between 1 and *n* users, each containing a `firstname`, `lastname`, `username` (or something like that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution would be to use [peppercorn](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/peppercorn/dev/).  Although it does not support the syntax you're looking for, it will let you send structured data to your Pyramid application through the use of forms.  [A more casual description](http://plope.com/peppercorn) exists too.

Comment: This seems to be close enough to what I'm looking for, thanks!  I do wish there was a 'better' (or more elegant) way of doing it, though.

Comment: If you hear of one, let me know.  In the meantime, heap scorn upon the original developers of HTML forms, whom I'm pretty sure ate soup with their hands.