# Correct way to make list or array from HTML Input controls

Tags: html, arrays, forms

I've seen people doing this:

`<input type="text" name="myText[]">`

What is the purpose of the `[]`?  Is it supposed to autoindex so you get an array or list at the server when the form is submitted?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose is to simulate an array. If you have 10 inputs named `images[]`, you can access their values (in PHP) like this :

```
foreach ($_POST['images'] as $img)
{
 // do something
}
```

Comment: That's what I thought, but is this a PHP only thing?  I am using a Python server and when I loop over request.params.items(), using your example, I get `images[], images[], images[] ...`

Comment: Looks like it's not implemented in Pyramid (my server). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734702/html-form-name-array-parsing-in-pyramid-python

Comment: I believe it's a general behaviour

Comment: for anyone trying to do this with Python Pyramid, checkout the Peppercorn module.. its very cool

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Its used to create an array... so you can have multiple inputs with the same name and processes them in php as an array.  If you want to access the individual elements in jquery/javascript then give each of them a unique ID and/or class.

Comment: It validates using the firefox extension.  HTML just treats it as a name.  PHP interprets it as an array.  The javascript engine doesn't know how to interpret the special character. 

@MFB not sure about Python.