# How can I get all the unique elements from a list that auto-grows to POST?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, pyramid

I created a list that auto-grows as new content is added. It's a simple example for me to learn with that allows people to add their siblings and their age (here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/bhamU).  I added a submit button to the code and am sending it to a url to be processed.

**Html:**

```
<form>
<div class="family">
    <input name="age" value=0>  <input name="sibling" value="name?">
    <hr />
</div>
</form>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$("form").on('keydown',"input[name='age']:last", function() {
    $('.family:last').clone().insertAfter(".family:last");
})
```

The problem is, if I enter:

```
 Bob - 25 
 Cindy - 24 
 Greg - 26
```

The results I get are:

```
 Greg - 26
 Greg - 26
 Greg - 26
```

The number of results are always the same as the number of siblings I enter but the actual results are always the last entry repeated. (I'm using Pyramid and using the `request.POST` command to see what's being posted).

I'm wondering if this is because I'm cloning the two inputs and their names are being repeated?  Is there something I should be doing to make the forms identifiable after cloning?

I am using this to get the data:

```
def submitchange(request):
    for x in request.POST:
        print x, ' = ', request.POST[x]
```

It outputs the correct number of inputs but all items are a duplicate of the last entry.

Comment: Always include the code from your fiddle in your question body.

Comment: What language are you using server-side? For PHP at least, adding [] to the end of the input's name makes it expect multiple values.

Comment: @AtkinsSJ I'm using the pyramid framework which is python based. I added [] to the end but I got a python error saying invalid syntax

Comment: @WesleyMurch I just updated the question with the code.

Comment: I found another SO question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734702/html-form-name-array-parsing-in-pyramid-python It looks like you need to use a module named peppercorn.

Comment: @AtkinsSJ I didn't know that I needed a module for this, thought it could handle it because I can get post requests already.  I'll check the module out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

that's because they have similar `name` attributes, you should change their `name` attributes after cloning. try this:

```
<form>
<div class="family">
    <input name="age_1" value=0>  <input name="sibling1" value="name?">
    <hr />
</div>
</form>
```

```
$("form").on('blur',"input[name^='age']:last", function() {
    var name = parseInt(this.name.slice(-1), 10)
    $('.family:last').clone().insertAfter(".family:last");
    $('.family:last').find('input[name^="age"]').attr('name', 'age_'+(name+1)).val("")
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bhamU/2/)

Answer (score 4):

Well, your original code was very-very close to being functional and I regret to say that the accepted answer is sub-optimal. I mean, it may work now, but imagine you decided to add the ability to delete and re-order the items - you'd need to keep re-numbering elements in your form after each operation, which would add a lot of complexity on the client.

Then, on the server, you'd need to somehow find all "name_1", "name_2", ... "name_n" parameters in POST... I'm not sure how to do this in a way which is not... err... unattractive. Maybe you'd need to pass a hidden variable in the form with the total number of rows? That would simplify the matter a bit.

Anyway, here's how real ninjas do this:

1. When a form is submitted, if several controls with the same name exist in the form, they're all are sent to the server. HTTP spec [specifies this explicitly](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#checkbox) only for checkboxes, but if you read the rest of the spec, it implicitly allows this for other controls too. Anyway, every single browser does send multiple name-value pairs for multiple controls - you can verify this using Firebug or just by changing the form method to GET - the URL will look like `?name=John+Smith&name=Joann+Smith&name=Bob+Smith`. The elements are also guaranteed to be sent in the order they appear in the form. Pyramid's `deform` form library relies heavily on this fact (via the [peppercorn](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/peppercorn/en/latest/?awesome) library, but that's in no way required for your task).
2. Pyramid request's POST and GET attributes may look like dictionaries, but in fact they're instances of [MultiDict](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/interfaces.html?highlight=multidict#pyramid.interfaces.IMultiDict) class - which is a dict-like thingie which can contain multiple values for a given key.

When you access request.POST['param_name'], the MultiDict returns the last "scalar" value added to the list - one would expect that it would automatically return a list if multiple values were encountered in the form, but that would be too error-prone, as the value would either be a scalar if there was just a single element or magically turn into a list of there's more than one element.

So, if you know that multiple values should be passed for a given key in your form, you may retrieve them using  `getall(key)` method. In your example:

```
def submitchange(request):
    for x in request.POST:
        print x, ' = ', request.POST.getall(x)
```

And that should be it!

In addition, here's a nice article from Chris McDonough explaining everything in great details: [Peppercorn: A Simpler Way to Decode Form Submission Data](http://www.plope.com/peppercorn) - in case you decide to do a little further and instead of getting two lists on the server:

```
name = ["a", "b", "c"]
age = ["10, "20, "30"]
```

have a list of *records*:

```
[
{'name': 'a',
 'age': 10
},
{'name': 'b',
 'age': 20
},
{'name': 'c',
 'age': 30
},

]
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm wondering if this is because I'm cloning the two inputs and their
>   names are being repeated? Is there something I should be doing to make
>   the forms identifiable after cloning?

Yes, you should.

```
var i = 1;
$("form").on('keydown',"input[name='age']:last", function() {
    var a = $('.family:last').clone();
    a.insertAfter(".family:last");
    i++;
    $($('.family:last input')[0]).attr('name', 'age'+i);
    $($('.family:last input')[1]).attr('name', 'sibling'+i);

})
    ​
```